# Graph quirk or bug? Nodes becoming merged in return

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have set up a graph gist to show my problem: http://gist.neo4j.org/?dropbox-2900504%2Fnames.adoc

I have the problem that if I don't specifically return the person node, or person id, two of my person nodes get merged into one for the return. They both have the same second name and the same labels on the person node (id 3 and 4, Tom and Sarah Smith).

If I add a label to the person node, as with James Smith (id 1) in this example, there is no problem. If I were to remove his :Foo label he would also be merged in with Sarah and Tom in query 2.

**If this is not a bug, is there a way for me to return these people distinctly without the person id or node being returned?**

I have shown the problem in the above gist, with the only difference between the two queries being that the second one also returns the person id.

Many thanks for your help,

tekiegirl

**Edit:**

How I want my results to look (basically like query 3 in the gist, but without the person id):

```
labels         names
[Person, Bar]  [Sally, Jones]
[Person, Foo]  [James, Smith]
[Person]       [Sarah, Smith]
[Person]       [Tom, Smith]
```

Comment: I have included Wes' solution at the end of the gist now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe you're not expecting the aggregation behavior you get with `collect`. Is this what you're trying to get?

```
MATCH (:Club { name:'FooFighters' })-[:MEMBER]->(p:Person)-[r:NAMED]->(n:Name) 
RETURN labels(p) AS labels, n.content AS names 
ORDER BY r.order, names
```

Update with more info, and now I understand what you were doing with your multiple names and order by in the WITH:

`collect` actually does an implicit group by on the other terms, making them distinct and grouping on them. If you want to group on person, then you need to include person `p` in the WITH/RETURN that you're `collect`ing in. Here's a rewrite. You can avoid returning `p` if you want, in the last return statement:

```
MATCH (:Club{name:'FooFighters'})-[:MEMBER]->(p:Person)-[r:NAMED]->(n:Name)
WITH p, n, r
ORDER BY r.order
WITH p, labels(p) as labels, collect(n.content) as names
RETURN labels, names
ORDER BY names[length(names)-1], names[0]
```

http://gist.neo4j.org/?8008646

Comment: Hi @Wes, Many thanks for your suggestion, but with what you have given me I get each name separately (see the gist, I have added it to the end http://gist.neo4j.org/?dropbox-2900504%2Fnames.adoc). Maybe I will just have to return the person id to get it to work correctly, if that is how collect behaves.

Comment: Can you post how you want your results to look?

Comment: Hi @Wes, I have added how I want the results to look. Many thanks :)

Comment: I get it. Ok, adding more.

Comment: I realize this may not be your exact use case, but is there some reason you're not using an array of names or a plain string for name on the person node?

Comment: Great, thank you @Wes, that worked exactly as I wanted. The reason I have the names as nodes is because I want everyone who has the name 'Steve' to be connected and everyone who have the name 'Jones' to be connected, etc. It is so I can search by name and name alternates really quickly :)